# C++ std::shared_pointer with template base class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to pass a derived class as a std::shared_pointer to a function whose parameter is the base class, which has a template.

Here is a full example:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
 public:
  std::string typeName()
  {
    int status;
    char *realName = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), 0, 0, &status);
    std::string ret(realName);

    free(realName);

    return ret;
  }
};

class Derived : public Base<float> {};
```

The function I would like to call is the 'doSomething' with the shared pointer.

```
template <class V>
void doSomethingNotShared(Base<V> *test)
{
  std::cout << "Not shared type: " << test->typeName() << std::endl;
};

template <class V>
void doSomething(std::shared_ptr<Base<V>> test)
{
  std::cout << "Shared type: " << test->typeName() << std::endl;
};
```

And here is the main function to show how I'd like to use it and pointing out the compilation error.

```
int main()
{

  std::shared_ptr<Derived> testval1 = std::shared_ptr<Derived> (new Derived());
  doSomething(testval1); // <- Compilation error

  Derived *testval2 = new Derived();
  doSomethingNotShared(testval2);

  std::shared_ptr<Base<float>> testCast = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Base<float>>(testval1); // Would rather not have to do this if there is another way ...
  doSomething(testCast); // <- No error runs fine
}
```

Is there any way to make this work with `doSomething(testval1);`? I am hoping to not have to use `dynamic_pointer_cast` (or any other type of casting mechanism) and just use Derived.

The main error is: `std::shared_ptr<Derived> is not derived from std::shared_ptr<Base<V> >`

I could create a "AnyBase" class that removes the template parameter, but then that would remove some of the type safety that I have in place in my actual application, which is a must.

One thing I'm considering is create a mapping between the new class `AnyBase` and `std::shared_ptr<AnyBase>`, then use the function `doSomethingNotShared` for handling the type safety, and using the lookup mapping to get the shared_ptr. (see below)

```
std::map<AnyBase *, std::shared_ptr<AnyBase>>
```

edit:

Example for checking type safety from my application:

```
template <class V, class W, class X>
void addRuleEdge(Bookkeeper<V> *bookkeeper, std::shared_ptr<IRule<V, W>> rule, ITask<W, X> *consumer)
```

In this case I want to have matching types between the `Bookkeeper` for `V` in the first template type of `IRule` and matching types for the second template parameter of `IRule` (`W`) with the first template type for `ITask`. This is used as an API call for users to ensure when adding an edge the types line up correctly at compile-time.

Comment: Since you are up casting `static_pointer_cast` is suitable.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to just call doSomething(testval1); ... So no casting whatsoever. The dynamic cast was to show of one method to be able to use the doSomething function with the templated shared_ptr.

Comment: I know.  Just letting you know the dynamic cast is not needed when up casting.  Looks like they only have a converting constructor if the object is a temporary.  They wont automatically convert a lvalue.

Comment: Looks like I need to edit to clarify that I do not want to use any form of casting if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to change `doSomething` to handle a broader set of arguments.

```
template <class V>
void doSomething(std::shared_ptr<V> test)
{
    std::cout << "Shared type: " << test->typeName() << std::endl;
};
```

Edit: Using your latest example, I've written an example for how you can achieve what you want with a broader overload and `std::enable_if` or `static_assert`. I've supplied empty classes to allow the example to compile.

```
#include <memory>

template<class V>
class Bookkeeper {};

template<class V, class W>
class IRule {};

// Some rule class derived from IRule compatible with Bookkeepr
class RealRule : public IRule<int, float> {};

template<class W, class X>
class ITask {};

// Some task class derived from ITask, compatible with RealRule
class RealTask : public ITask<float, double> {};

// Some task class derived from ITask, not compatible with RealRule
class BadTask : public ITask<int, double> {};

template <class V, class Rule, class W, class X>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<IRule<V, W>, Rule>::value, void>::type
addRuleEdge(Bookkeeper<V> *bookkeeper, std::shared_ptr<Rule> rule, ITask<W, X> *consumer)
{
    // Do work
}

int main()
{
    Bookkeeper<int> my_book_keeper;
    auto my_rule = std::make_shared<RealRule>();
    RealTask my_task;

    // Compiles
    addRuleEdge(&my_book_keeper, my_rule, &my_task);

    BadTask bad_task;

    // Won't compile (no matching overload)
    addRuleEdge(&my_book_keeper, my_rule, &bad_task);
}
```

You can also choose to use `static_assert` if you simply want to be notified when the wrong types are used.

```
template <class V, class Rule, class W, class X>
void addRuleEdge(Bookkeeper<V> *bookkeeper, std::shared_ptr<Rule> rule, ITask<W, X> *consumer)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<IRule<V, W>, Rule>::value, "Type mismatch!");
    // Do work
}

int main()
{
    Bookkeeper<int> my_book_keeper;
    auto my_rule = std::make_shared<RealRule>();
    RealTask my_task;

    // Compiles
    addRuleEdge(&my_book_keeper, my_rule, &my_task);

    BadTask bad_task;

    // Won't compile (error "Type mismatch!")
    addRuleEdge(&my_book_keeper, my_rule, &bad_task);
}
```

Comment: Probably because your answer had casting and the OP did not want casts. (not the down voter)

Comment: Removing the Base class paremeter in the template argument for shared_ptr will remove the type safety that is used. Also `std::shared_ptr<V>`, does not define a function typeName().

Comment: @Jameshobbs I'm not sure I understand your comment. In this case `V` will be either `Base<float>` or `Derived` in which case `test` will provide the method `typeName()`. You seem to interpret this answer as me suggesting you use `std::shared_ptr<void> test`.

Comment: As long as `doSomething` is called with only `Base` or `Derived` then it should be okay. The more important thing is removing the template parameter for `Base`. I will try to provide an example as to what I am concerned with. It has to do with multiple parameters and 3 templates, where two of the 3 match the type.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot in the actual code. Looks extremely promising. Thanks for providing an example using my edit.

Comment: @Jameshobbs I've updated the example to use `std::is_base_of` which removes the need for `t_V` and t_W`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Integrated it into the code and it works like a charm. Decided to use the static_assert variant to just get the error message. Such a simple concept. Now if only the IDE would provide better feedback. I will just need to provide the necessary Doxygen comments to ensure people know exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like achievable with just a little bit of additional work.

First, begin by adding a type to the base class that aliases its template parameter:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
 public:

      typedef T type;

    // The rest of your base class is as it is before.
};
```

Now, tweak doSomething() slightly, to take an opaque shared pointer, and then figure out the base class it came from, then re-cast it:

```
template <class opaque_ptr>
void doSomething(std::shared_ptr<opaque_ptr> param)
{
   typedef typename opaque_ptr::type base_type;

   auto test = std::static_pointer_cast<Base<base_type>>(param);

   // Now your test is a std::shared_ptr<Base<T>>, proceed as before.
```

If you insist on passing `std::shared_ptr<Base<V>>` around, you have to type-convert it. `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` and `std::shared_ptr<Base<V>>` are not related to each other; one is not a derived class of the other one, so you cannot avoid recasting.

Comment: This is similar to using an AnyBase type and remove the template arguments. This would work, but I need the type safety that the template argument provides. However I really like the use of static_pointer_cast, which I might use in other places in my application. Really cool stuff.

Comment: The last paragraph in my answer explains why a cast is required. The static cast is just as typesafe, and if `opaque_ptr` is not derived from `Base<V>`, `base_type` will fail compilation.

Comment: The type safety within the parameters of `doSomething` is important to have. I've added an example within my application of what I mean.

Comment: All that type-safety in the parameters gets you is a different error message. Either way, not passing a derived class results in a compilation error, with the only difference being the actual error message. Now, it is true that moving the compilation failure to parameters does often result in a more meaningful error message. If you want to do that, it's a simple matter of using `std::enable_if` with `std::is_base_of`, together with the `type` declaration from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `shared_ptr<Base<V>>` is a type that can be converted-from a `shared_ptr<Derived>` but they are otherwise unrelated.

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct is_derived_from_template_of_helper {
  template<class...Ts>
  constexpr std::true_type operator()(Z<Ts...>*) const { return {}; }
  constexpr std::false_type operator()(...) const { return {}; }
};
template<template<class...>class Z, class T>
using is_derived_from_template_of_t =
  decltype(
    is_derived_from_template_of_helper<Z>{}(
      std::declval<std::decay_t<T>*>()
    )
  );
```

now we can do this:

```
template <class X,
  class=std::enable_if_t<
    is_derived_from_template_instance_of_t<Base, X>{}
  >
>
void doSomething(std::shared_ptr<X> test)
{
  std::cout << "Shared type: " << test->typeName() << std::endl;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/855c6cbfecdf544c).

[If you want to get types out](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dd42bd71d4fc081),

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct derived_from_template_args_tags_helper {
  template<class...Ts>
  constexpr std::tuple<tag_t<Ts>...> operator()(Z<Ts...>*) const { return {}; }
};
template<template<class...>class Z, class T, std::size_t I>
using derived_from_template_arg = typename std::tuple_element<I, decltype(derived_from_template_args_tags_helper<Z>{}(std::declval<std::decay_t<T>*>()))>::type::type;

template <class X,
  class=typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
      derived_from_template_arg<Base, X, 0>, float
    >{}
  >::type
>
void doSomething(std::shared_ptr<X> test)
{
  std::cout << "Shared float type: " << test->typeName() << std::endl;
}
```

but this gets exceedingly and increasingly complex.

Comment: This solution can be greatly simplified if `Base<T>` can derive from  common type, in which case you can use `std::is_base_of`.

Comment: This looks very interesting. How might this be applied to my example above in my edit: `template <class V, class W, class X> void addRuleEdge(Bookkeeper<V> *bookkeeper, std::shared_ptr<IRule<V, W>> rule, ITask<W, X> *consumer)`, also I cannot use C++14, but was able to use `std::enable_if` instead of `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True.  Also, I can make `is_derived_from_template_instance_of` an order of magnitude cleaner with a bit of thought.

Comment: @Jameshobbs Do a similar SFINAE restriction on `std::shared_ptr<IRule<V, W>> rule`?  If you want to insist that the `V` and `W` match at overload dispatch time, that is extra work.  Are you sure you want to bother?  A technique like `is_derived_from_template_of_helper` can be used to extract the arguments passed to the template base instance (return them in `template<class T> struct tag_t{using type=T;}:` tags instead of `true_type`/`false_type`s.  Then more SFINAE code can be added to validate them.

Comment: Ensuring the type safety from addEdge between V and W is important as it will cause really nasty errors down the line if someone misuses and passes non matching types. The way these types are used is to declare input and output types for tasks. So `bookkeeper` consumes data of type `V`, and passes `V` to a rule, which consumes `V` and produces `W` for the consumer task that consumes `W`. The purpose of the `shared_ptr` is to share across multiple different instances of `bookkeeper`. Another option is to just use a regular pointer and release at some appropriate time.. will be tricky.

Comment: @Jameshobbs The error should be compile time errors, no?  The compile time errors may be nasty.  You could even add clear static_assert errors that check that things work instead of insisting on doing it at overload time.  You only need overload SFINAE if you want alternative overloads to be considered, or want to be able to test outside if arguments are valid.